# Creating a Responsive Photo Gallery

Tags: css, background-image, responsive-design, photo-gallery

I am new to web design and am building a site for my artwork. I am stuck with how to properly build this photo gallery and have it positioned where I need it to be. The gallery must be positioned perfectly because it needs to line up with the background image that acts as the frame for the gallery images. I have designed this based on % in the attempt to eventually make it responsive to four different screen-size ranges. When I test what I have so far it just falls apart when it hits the different browsers. It does fine in dreamweaver's live view but when I test it in any browser either the background image won't show up, or the images stack up on the left side of the page, and it does not respond at all when I shrink the screen. The three main questions I have are - How can I get the background image to show up and the gallery images to stay in place? And how do I get the other CSS files to activate when the screen size changes ? But ANY AND ALL help is greatly appreciated.

Colin

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0 />
<title>Test</title>


<link rel"stylsheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:769px;) and (max-width:1088px;)" href="../_css/large.css" />

<link rel"stylsheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:449px;) and (max-width:768px;)" href="../_css/medium.css" />

<link rel"stylsheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:252px;) and (max-width:448px;)" href="../_css/small.css" />

<link href="../_css/main_full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="page_container">

        <div class="gallery_container">

                <a href="#"><img id="pos1" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/sunlight_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos2" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/clownflat_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos3" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/goldensun_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos4" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/monstertheatre_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos5" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/home_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos6" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/wishingstargallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos7" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/cozycave_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos8" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/coffeetable_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos9" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/breakaway_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos10" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/happyns_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos11" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/boymeetsgirl_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos12" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/sadbabygallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos13" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/salvation_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos14" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/orangestart_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos15" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/spaceobjectsgallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos16" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/clown_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos17" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/ponycave_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos18" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/pacha_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos19" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/goldstorm_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos20" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/qerogallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="pos21" src="../_images/galleryimages_full/theblues_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>

        </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE MAIN CSS - THE OTHER THREE STYLE-SHEETS ARE MEDIA QUERIES THAT I HAVE NOT BUILT YET.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Layout (global rules for fullsize) */

.page_container {
width: 1280px;
height: 3000px;
background-image: url(../_page_components/gallery/gallery_full.jpg);
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
position: relative;
/*padding-top: 19.541%; 248 pixels*/
}

.gallery_container {
width: 66.7%;  /* 853 pixels */
height: 55.3%; /* 1659 pixels */
/*margin: 19.541% auto 0% auto; - equal to 248px*/
padding: 19.4% 0% 0% 0%;
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
}

#pos1 {  /* Top Left Corner*/
padding-left: 0.3%;
padding-right: 4.91%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos2 {  /* Middle top row */
padding-left: 0.42%;    
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos3 {  /* Topr Right Corner */
padding-left: 5.35%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos4 {  /* The rest of the images/rows follow the same positioning pattern */
padding-left: 0.4%;
padding-right: 4.75%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos5 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos6 {
padding-left: 5.15%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
padding-right: 0.2%;
}

#pos7 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos8 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos9 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
 }

#pos10 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos11 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos12 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos13 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos14 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos15 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos16 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos17 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos18 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos19 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   

}

#pos20 {
padding-left: 0.5%; 

}

#pos21 {
padding-left: 5.25%;

 }
```

CSS MEDIA QUERY FILE FOR "LARGE" SCREENS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Layout Large Screens*/



.page_container {
width: 1088px;
height: 2550px;
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
background-image: url(../_page_components/gallery/gallery_large.jpg);
}
```

CSS MEDIA QUERY FILE FOR "MEDIUM" SCREENS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Layout Medium Screens */

.page_container {
width: 768px;
height: 1800px;
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
background-image: url(../_page_components/gallery/gallery_medium.jpg);
}
```

CSS MEDIA QUERY FILE FOR "SMALL" SCREENS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Layout Small Screens */

.page_container {
width: 448px;
height: 1050px;
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
background-image: url(../_page_components/gallery/gallery_small.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Hey twodayslate, I have set up a jsfiddle profile and plugged in this code. You can find it at http://jsfiddle.net/squigworm/FrsGp/3/  . Thank You for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: I have also put this code up on [www.colinbarclay.com](http://www.colinbarclay.com) so that the outcome can be seen. As I now realize no one can see it on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bgpic">
  <img src="../_page_components/gallery/gallery_full.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div

<div class="page_container">
</div> 

#bgpic {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#bgpic img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answering Carol, I will try to implement.